# Fail to draw on current keyframe

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

Basically,

When drawing with onion skin activated.

Normally after you paint your drawing it should stay where you put it.

But the problem I'm having is the drawing turned green (which is the onion skin of the previous frame)
[image: So I draw a line here]
[image: And after I release the mouse it turned green]
It seems it was drawn in the last frame.

And this had bothered me for days.

The frame rates was 25 in defult, had changed it to 24 before I start to do the animations, not sure if thats the problem.

Thanks for the time and the answers.
Hope I've written my questions clear, English is hard...

Comment: Don't worry, your English is perfect. As I don't think I've seen this problem before, would you be willing to upload your Blend file to let us investigate it for a solution? You can use this website. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi! thanks for the comment!
I've uploaded the file.
My goal is to make the birds flap their wings in the layer named "floating"

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention you need to give me the link to the blend file you uploaded. You can make a new comment, or edit your original question.

Comment: Here you go!

https://blend-exchange.com/b/0raxERdr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was tricky to work out but basically it's because you have a frame offset modifier with a Frame offset set to 1. So at any time, the frame you see is actually one frame ahead of the frame you're actually on.
That makes any new drawing go back by one frame as soon as you finish drawing, immediatly turning to the onion-skin greeenish colour.

Your problem will disappear if you either disable the modifier or set its Frame offset to 0.

Comment: I've tried the method and it does fix the problem!
Thanks for the help!